# Azure AD Signin from MVC: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, model-view-controller, azure-active-directory

**Reference**: [To Set up Azure AD Sign in from MVC App](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-ad-authentication-for-mvc-web-application/)

I followed the above link and I am getting the following error:

> Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)

By what I have read its said that this is because I am using the wrong tenant. However I have gone into ADD and gone to custom domains and both that are there(verified([domain.co.za] and available[domain.onmicrosoft.com]) are producing the same error.

Below is what I have in my web.config:

```
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="[Application Id]" />  
    <add key="ida:Tenant" value="[Domain]" />  
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />  
    <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44357/" />
```

Is there something else I am missing ?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the one thing that the tutorial I provided did not specify, was adding {0} to the AADInstance:

```
<add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}" />
```

Once I made this change, it worked.

Hope this helps someone else.

Cheers!