# Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found) with owin library

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, owin

I am trying to implement the Azure AD authentication on my ASP.NET MVC application (framework version 4.7.2).

[image]

All the required config values lie on the `web.config` file.

[image]

**AccountController.cs**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    // GET: Account
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public void SignIn()
    {
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/Default" },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
            );
        }
    }

    public void SignOut()
    {

        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
          OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
          CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
        );
    }
}
```

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

[image]

When I try to invoke the SignIn method it always shows an error, like the below image.

[image]

Comment: The connection completed, authenticated, and then server did not find the route ("/Default").

Comment: I see your SignIn is a Void instead of a Task and not sure how the controller is doing the mapping. Could you please share a but more information regarding the Controller?

Comment: @jdweng it's already mentioned in the  routes.MapRoute section in RouteConfig file. I expect It will redirect to the '/Home/Index' page.

Comment: @JuanMedina I added the controller code in the question Thank you

Comment: It is not working.  Debug the server and find out why it is failing.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#set-up-conventional-route

Comment: I am really clueless, If the route config path is correct then why it shows this 404 issue?

Comment: @RageshPRaju Do you have a /Home/Index endpoint defined in your application? because the current /Default will redirect there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error occurred as you missed adding `{0}` to the AADInstance key in your **Web.config** file.

I followed this [blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-ad-authentication-for-mvc-web-application/) by *@ayoub* to implement the Azure AD authentication in my .NET MVC application (framework 4.7.2).

When I click **`Sign In`** button without adding `{0}` to the AADInstance key  in **Web.config** file, I too got **same error**:

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="appID" />  
    <add key="ida:Tenant" value="xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com" />  
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />  
    <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44353/" />
</appSettings>
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to add  `{0}` at the end of your AADInstance key value by modifying **Web.config** file:

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="appID" />  
    <add key="ida:Tenant" value="xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com" />  
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}" />  
    <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44353/" />
</appSettings>
```

Now, I ran the project again by making above change and got below screen with `Sign In` button:

[image]

When I clicked `Sign in` button, I got below screen to pick Azure AD account:

[image]

Once sign in successful, it took me to `/Home/Index` page:

[image]

**Reference:**
[asp.net mvc - Azure AD Signin from MVC: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)  by **AxleWack**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55099743/azure-ad-signin-from-mvc-response-status-code-does-not-indicate-success-404-n?rq=2)